# Is it possible for Instance.new to be added in an if statement

Tags: roblox

I need some help with a Roblox script! I'm a beginner you see and I'm learning how to use if statements. They're simple but, I want to add an "Instance. New("Part") here's an example:

if game.Lighting.TimeOfDay == "12:00:00" then
local part = Instance.new("Part")
end

Will this work? also is there a way I can get a flashlight for example when it becomes 3 AM, is that also possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for Instance.new to be added inside an if statement

The most simple answer is yes, it is possible. But a better title for your question would be :

> How do I give a player a Tool at a specific time?

And your code would only work if it was executed at the *exact* second that the time was "03:00:00". So because that's unlikely to happen, you need a way to repeatedly check the time.

Other answers have recommended using a loop with the `wait(seconds)` function as way to repeatedly check what time it is. But this runs into an issue where if the wait interval is too large, you might go from "02:59:59" to "03:00:01" and miss that crucial moment where it is exactly "03:00:00". Alternatively, if the wait interval is too short, your code might fire multiple times when the time is "03:00:00". So you need something to make sure that your code only fires once when the right time comes. I would recommend using the [Lighting.Changed signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Instance/Changed) instead. This way, rather than you asking what the time is, it will tell you whenever it changes.

The next thing to keep in mind is that [Lighting.TimeOfDay](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Lighting/TimeOfDay) doesn't change until you tell it to. So time can move as quickly or as slowly as you tell it, but you must script it to change. You can do this by setting the [Lighting.ClockTime](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Lighting/ClockTime) or the [Lighting:SetMinutesAfterMidnight() function.](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Lighting/SetMinutesAfterMidnight)

The last piece is to find a flashlight. I would recommend just grabbing one of the [Tools](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Tool) out of the Toolbox and adding it as a child of the [Script](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script).

A full example of what that might look like is here. Imagine this is a Script in [ServerScriptService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ServerScriptService) that has a flashlight Tool as a child of the Script.

```
local Lighting = game:GetService("Lighting")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

-- 1) grab a reference to the flashlight Tool
local flashlightTool = script.Flashlight


-- 2) create a different thread to handle time changes
spawn(function()
    -- round the number to avoid floating point math issues
    local oneSecond = tonumber(string.format("%.4f", 1.0 / 3600.0))
    
    -- progress the time of day
    while true do
        -- to speed up time, multiply oneSecond by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, or any factor of 60
        -- this will ensure that minutes are still hit on time
        Lighting.ClockTime += oneSecond
        wait(1.0)
    end
end)



-- 3) listen for when the time of day changes
Lighting.Changed:Connect(function(propertyName)
    if propertyName == "TimeOfDay" then
        --print("Time of Day changed : ", Lighting.TimeOfDay)
        
        if Lighting.TimeOfDay == "03:00:00" then
            -- give everyone a flashlight
            warn("IT'S 3 AM")
            local players = Players:GetPlayers()
            for i, player in ipairs(players) do
                -- check if they already have one, and escape if they do
                if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild(flashlightTool.Name) then
                    continue
                end

                local flashlight = flashlightTool:Clone()
                flashlight.Parent = player.Backpack
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code and paste it to localscript // StarterGui why I put a loops? so it can check when time get changed. You need a remotes so it can visible to every player in your game if you don't use remotes it only visible to one player

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events

```
delay(0, function()
while true do wait(.1)
    if game.Lighting.TimeOfDay == "12:00:00" then
        print("Time Changed")
        --Put Your Code Here

    end
end
end)
```